# Does Intensified Spell Work on Ball Lightning?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, metamagic

As the title states, I simply would like to know if intensified spell will add an extra ball when I cast Ball Lightning.

Answer (score 5):

## The feat [Intensified Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic) does almost nothing when used to modify the spell [*ball lightning*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/ball-lightning)

The dice of damage dealt by the spell [*ball lighting*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/ball-lightning) aren't based on the *ball lightning* spell's caster's level. The only thing the feat Intensify Spell does if applied to the spell *ball lightning* is cause the modified spell to *either* occupy a higher level spell lot if it's prepared *or* make the caster spend a higher level spell slot if cast without preparation. The feat won't otherwise affect the spell.

The benefit of the feat [Intensified Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic), in part, says, "An intensified spell increases the maximum number of damage dice by 5 levels," yet the spell [*ball lightning*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/ball-lightning) creates at least one globe of electricity that, if it enter "a space with a creature,… stops moving for the round and deals 3d6 points of electricity damage to that creature," an amount of damage not based on caster level *at all*.

The benefit of the feat Intensify Spell goes on to says, "No other variables of the spell are affected, and spells that inflict damage that is not modified by caster level are not affected by this feat," making it so there's just no way a caster *can* get an extra ball (a variable unrelated to damage but which is related to caster level) from an intensified *ball lighting* spell.

Comment: Aparently the last line of the feat actually makes it so you cannot apply intensify spell to ball lightning at all.